# Attachments getting corrupt/not openable after composing mail using nodemailer mail-composer and Gmail API

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data, gmail-api, mime-types, nodemailer

I have been trying to create a simple mailer API hosted on AWS Lambda, using Gmail APIs.

I am parsing multipart/form-data using `aws-lambda-multipart-parser` . I created the mail body using Nodemailer's Mailcomposer.

When I send the mail, the attachment files are appearing corrupt and I am not able open them.

```js
import multipart from 'aws-lambda-multipart-parser'

import MailComposer from 'nodemailer/lib/mail-composer';
import { JWT } from "google-auth-library"

import { google } from 'googleapis'
import privatekey from './../../gw-mailer/gw_mailer_service_keys.json' // This was downloaded when you created your Service Account Key

const scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'];
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  // console.log(event.body)
  const body = multipart.parse(event, false);
  // const body = await parser.parse(event);

  const file = [{
    filename: body.attachments.filename,
    content: body.attachments.content,
    contentType: body.attachments.contentType,
  }]

  console.log(file)


  const mail = new MailComposer({
    from: 'from@email.xxx',
    to: 'to@email.xxx',
    subject: 'Test',
    text: 'Test message',
    attachments: file
  })

  const message = await mail.compile().build()

  // console.log(message)

  sendMail(message)

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
  }
}


const sendMail = async (message) => {
  const jwtClient = new JWT({
    email: privatekey.client_email,
    key: privatekey.private_key,
    scopes,
    subject: 'dev@gushwork.ai',
  });
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: jwtClient });

  const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
    userId: 'me',
    requestBody: {
      raw: Buffer.from(message).toString('base64')
    }
  });
}
```

Where am i going wrong here?

I have tried playing around with encoding and mimetypes, but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

if your attachments are URL photos, then only use path and cid. DO NOT USE OR ASSIGN FILENAME, learned that the hard way.

when i assigned a filename, the photo attachments would attach in email but would not show image. would only show filename and when i clicked on it it was like 23bytes and not able to open it. As soon as I removed the filename part in my code it started working like a charm. makes sense